# Counting combinations with constraints in a harmonic sequence

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

given the harmonic sequence 1, 1/2, 1/3... till 1/N, for some given positive integer N. Let i be an integer and T be a real number. What are the number of ways that I can pick i points from the sequence such that the sum of the series between any pair (equivalently, any 2 points following each other) is at least T. A tight lower bound is sufficient. Thank you!